replace функция в Python [переменные]
Учась писать на питоне, столкнулся с проблемой в калькуляторе уравнений. Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно вставить в место нового текста переменную answer:
statys = True
run = True
answer = 1
while statys:
    example = input("Введите уравнение без равенства")
    raw = input('Введите равенство уравнения')
    while run:
        answer += 1
        x ="x"
        exans = example.replace("x", answer)
        print(exans)
        if exans == raw:
            print(example + raw)
            break
        else:
            continue

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Читайте эти ошибки и исследуйте причину их появления, что тут ещё сказать

Добавьте эти ошибки у вопрос (полностью). Изменить вопрос - кнопка [edit].

Пока что, без текста ошибок, можно сказать, что скорее всего выражение str(example1 + str(answer) + example3) выдаёт что-то не то. Попробуйте его распечатать и посмотреть, что там.

...а теперь вопрос вообще другой стал и непонятно в чём проблема-то

answer = 1 - число! example - строка! Так делать replace нельзя! А что, у Вас в Вашей среде разработки ошибку как результат выполнения не пишут?

Это дубликат вот этой темы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1591800/python-replace-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5
