python replace (переменные)
столкнулся с проблемой что не могу в виде второго аргумента replace передать переменную (10 строка) прикрепил код что бы было видно на примере
statys = True
run = True
answer = 1
while statys:
    example = input("Введите уравнение без равенства")
    raw = input('Введите равенство уравнения')
    while run:
        answer += 1
        x ="x"
        exans = example.replace("x", answer)
        print(exans)
        if exans == raw:
            print(example + raw)
            break
        else:
            continue


выше написано statys = True

Если память не изменяет: str.replace(str, str, int) - следовательно answer = 1 -> str(answer)

Может я ошибаюсь, но answer = 1 - это число, а example - строка.

exans = example.replace("x", str(answer))

Так будет корректнее, как уже заметили ранее, replace работает со строками, поэтому вам необходимо выполнить преобразование типов от int к str или chr

Что это за тип chr в питоне?

Я выразился не совсем правильно, имел ввиду одиночный символ, т.е. строку длиной 1
